# Can't figure it out which variable exactly is trying to call "Undefined Variable: user"

Tags: php, slim, raintpl

I'm practicing with a e-commerce project and in the backoffice when trying to edit a user this error occurs but I couldn't figure it out what the problem is.
This is the error I'm getting:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrg0s.png)

I don't understand why does it says that the variable $user is not defined in this case

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use \Slim\Slim;
use \Hcode\Page;
use \Hcode\PageAdmin;
use \Hcode\Model\User;

$app = new Slim();

$app->config('debug', true);
```

---

```
$app->get("/admin/users/:iduser", function($iduser) {

    User::verifyLogin();

    $page = new PageAdmin();

    $page->setTpl("users-update"); 
});
```

This is the code created from raintpl, the error is said to be in the first line above with the $user:

```
        <form role="form" action="/admin/users/<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $user["iduser"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?>" method="post">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="desperson">Nome</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desperson" name="desperson" placeholder="Digite o nome" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $user["desperson"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="deslogin">Login</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deslogin" name="deslogin" placeholder="Digite o login"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $user["deslogin"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nrphone">Telefone</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="nrphone" name="nrphone" placeholder="Digite o telefone"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $user["nrphone"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="desemail">E-mail</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="desemail" name="desemail" placeholder="Digite o e-mail" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $user["desemail"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE ); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inadmin" value="1" <?php if( $user["inadmin"] == 1 ){ ?>checked<?php } ?>> Acesso de Administrador
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The page with the forms should load properly

Project repository if more information needed
https://github.com/i-nunes/ecommerce

Comment: Where did you define the $user variable? Do you need to pass it to the template?

Comment: As previous comment points out, you need to let the template engine know about variable assignments. See rainTPL docs to learn how https://github.com/feulf/raintpl3/wiki/Documentation-for-PHP-developers

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Because the last code that I shared (where the error occurs) is created by the tpl.
I'm not sure exactly where I should define first. (I'm doing this project within a course and in the course they didn't define it before).